# How do I complete the 8.4.13 Owls, Part 2 problem in CodeHS Python?

Tags: python

So the assignment says:

In addition to just reporting how many words contained the word owl, you should report the *indices* at which the words occurred!
Here's an example run of your program might look like:

```
Enter some text: Owls are so cool! I think snowy owls might be my faborite. Or maybe spotted owls.
There were 3 words that contained "owl".
They occurred at indices: [0, 7, 15]
```

This is what I have so far for my code:

```
sentence = input("Talk about something: ")
sentence.lower()

print "There are " + str(sentence.count("owls)) + " of the word \"owls\" in the sentence"
print "They occurred at indices: " + str(sentence.findl("owls")
```

But that only prints the first index it's found at, how do I get it to print all of the indexes it's found at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sentence = 'Owls are so cool! I think snowy owls might be my faborite. Or maybe spotted owls.'
words = [i for i, word in enumerate(sentence.split(' ')) if 'owl' in word.lower()]
```

This works.